# Why does a function outside useEffect get called while a function inside useEffect without dependency array doesn't?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state, rerender

Until today I thought that code inside an useEffect without dependency array and code outside useEffect both trigger on every rerender, but then I found this weird case and I don't understand why is this happening.

In [THIS](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-carson-tpgz3?file=/src/App.js) example, the first time you click the button it triggers a setState to a different value so it rerenders and both console.log are called, but the second time you click the button a setState is called with the same value, still **the outside console.log gets called, but the console.log inside useEffect doesn't... why?** Is this not a full rerender? How can the component get reevaluated without triggering useEffect again?

The next time you click the button nothing happens because calling setState with the same value doesnt trigger a rerender, but the first time does that weird half-rerender thing that I dont understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my question:

This behavior is actually explained in the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) and nothing to worry about since it's not a "real" render.

This is the relevant part:

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state,
> React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.
> [...]

So basically React evaluates the function, so the outside console.log will be called but then it just bails out without rerendering the children or firing useEffect

Comment: what is the point of evaluating the function, if react knows the state has not changed?

Comment: @AntoineWeber maybe it has to do it to know if the state or anything else changed :/