# Double rendering of page using Laravel + React + Breeze

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs, laravel-breeze

Fresh install without any modification beside a console.log that is located on welcome.jsx and it is displayed twice. What can I do to fix this? This will affect all other functionalities all axios, if there will be, will be executed twice. How can I fix this? Thank you

I have tested with fresh install of laravel + inertia only and it happens too. I have instaled them on dedicated server and localhost too. I have tried laravel + breeze too same problem.

[This is my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQMek.png)
[this is the composer.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTpka.png)

the console.log in the Welcome.jsx [the change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTXoD.png)
the console in the browser's console [the double log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMJ9P.png)

i run it with npm run dev and npm run build for both is the same.

Comment: How do you run your project can you post that

Comment: npm run build
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build && vite build --ssr"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.2",
        "@inertiajs/react": "^1.0.0",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "postcss": "^8.4.18",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    }

Comment: I think if you followed the starter kit correctly you should just run like ```npm run dev```

Comment: @dGame Please [edit] your question and post relevant information there, not in the comments. Thanks

Comment: @tp45 same on npm run dev and for a production site you will run build not dev
thank you for trying to help me

Comment: @brombeer i have add package.json and composer.json please let me know if you need more info I can provide anything. thank you for trying to help

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Does it send two identical requests and get the same result from both? Can you share an example pair of requests that are duplicated? (incl. request and response headers)

Comment: I just create a fresh install following https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits everything is fine. Please show us what it shows when you run it locally and also show the console

Comment: @apokryfos fresh install add a console.log in the return area, and after build you will see that console.log twice in the browser console.

Comment: @tp45 please check I have add the prints in the post.

Comment: I managed to reproduce the double console, I added the console and ran ```npm run build```  then php artisan serv and it console logged twice , I don't think this is a problem and it will not course problems for you try logging somewhere else and check

Comment: @tp45 if you add any axios for example it will be executed twice which can cause problems... we as company are making sports betting sites and we need axios requests and its strange to be executed twice. Thank you so much for checking.

Answer (score 0):

Use useEffect to make sure nothing executes twice like below

```
 useEffect(() => {
        console.log(user); // this runs once
        axios
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data); // this runs once
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, []);
```

I run php artisan serv and run npm run dev for hot reload every time I make changes
[image]

Here is my console
[image]

Comment: yes, that is correct, but still that console.log it is displayed twice and all the html that is on that return.

Comment: if you console log anywhere in react it will console multiple time please check this and you can go to their docs as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67307443/why-does-a-function-outside-useeffect-get-called-while-a-function-inside-useeffe the html part I don't understand

Comment: if you have:
https://imgur.com/6cUSzNF somethig like this and the useEffect is inside Announcement it will be executed twice